# Why is the last iteration given, instead of the current one?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some PHP & HTML code which fetches id's, names & statuses from a mysql database.

Using  buttons and $_POST i'm attempting to update the MYSQL database when said the users button is clicked (it's a simple in/out board)

Here is my code

```
<?php 
include 'confile.php';
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

echo $_POST['update']. " "; //test to show correct name
echo $_POST['staffid']; //test to show the correct staffid << **THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS**
//$incid = $_POST['staffid'];

//$sql = "SELECT status FROM staff WHERE id=$incid";
//$result = $conn->query($sql);
//echo $result; //show the status

} else {
    //do nothing.
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<title>Staff Board</title>
<body>
<div align="center" class="header">
    <div class="header text">
        <h1>Staff Board</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header logo">
    <img src="/assets/img/logo.gif" width="64px" height="64px">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="conbox" align="center" class="content">
<hr>

<?php
//get all staff and their statuses
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, surname, status FROM $staff ORDER BY surname ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        // assign results to values
        $id = $row["id"]; 
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $surname = $row["surname"];
        $status = $row["status"];
        $fullname = $firstname . " " . $surname . " " . $id;  //The $id variable will be dropped from here... it's just for testing. note, it works here, the correct ID is added to the button value

        if ($status == 1) { //pick the correct color for the status
            $color = "butGreen";
        } else {
            $color = "butRed";
        }
?>
    <form class="staffGrid" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="staffid" name="staffid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($id); ?>"/> <!-- hidden input to pass the id to $_POST -->
    <input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fullname); ?>"/> <!-- submit button to trigger POST -->
    </form> <!-- added as per devpro & billyonecan -->
    <?php
    };
    ?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I first load the page, the buttons show correctly, and there is no test output at the top of the page, which I expect.

however, when I click a button, the page refreshes correctly, and shows the correct name for the button being pushed (from the echo on line 5), but the wrong staffid is given. It gives the LAST id for the while loop, instead of correct value for that button.

I had assumed that for each iteration, the values would be set for that specific element (the button)... obviously i'm incorrect here.

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?**

---

Additional info

Confile.php has  the following variables used in the code:-

```
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);
$staff = [Location of db table]
```

some output :-

```
echo $sql;
SELECT id, firstname, surname, status FROM inout.staff ORDER BY surname ASC


echo print_r($_POST);
Array ( [staffid] => 17 [update] => First Second 8 )
```

Comment: where's your form's closing tag?

Comment: `SELECT id, firstname, surname, status FROM $staff ORDER BY surname ASC` in query from where you are getting `$staff` ??

Comment: @billyonecan Which opening tag are you looking at?

Comment: @devpro They are variables in confile.php. I've not included it as I didn't think it required.

Comment: u can add more options for debug as you are doing, step1) `echo $sql;` and share the result here, step2) `print_r($_POST);` check what r u getting and share the result

Comment: echo $sql will give = SELECT id, firstname, surname, status FROM inout.staff ORDER BY surname ASC"

Comment: @Stese `<form>...`, where's `</form>`? That's probably the issue (you're overwriting the values because your inputs use the same name)

Comment: `$fullname = $firstname . " " . $surname . " " . $id;` if its working fine, then check the last part `</form>` is missing in your code. second what is the result of `print_r(#_POST)`

Comment: I advise you to separate template from code logic. Create a separate PHP file to handle form submission.

Comment: added the </form> tag below the buttons, edited this in my question... it fixes the issue but breaks the grid layout i'll work on this.

Comment: great @Stese good work. now i am closing your question because its just a typo error

Comment: @Devpro : as you solved it, do you want to provide an answer? I'll drop the edit so it all makes sense. :) (billyonecan could also claim credit there, since thats the first comment!)

Comment: it just a typo error, so no need to add answer... but your debugging skills is good. like it.

Comment: [This might help you structure your code.](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/08/31/using-the-twig-templating-engine-in-php/)

Comment: @gview no thanks. I prefer to learn/develop without extra tools possibly obfuscating issues.

Comment: @Stese: with all due respect to you, your code reveals you are a rank novice.  If you truly understand PHP you have to understand that it can not be obfuscated, as it's interpreted.  Your approach WILL be the opposite of DRY -- this is clear given that you have markup where you are echoing out an entire HTML page within each script.  In summary, professional PHP involves the use of component libraries.  Best of luck to you with your projects.

Comment: Thats my point, I'm a novice. I'd rather get it working without other tools doing things that I just simply don't understand. I see no learning benefit of that. Just because there are libraries that make things 'easier' for some people to use them, doesn't mean it's a good idea to use them from the start. I tend to actually understand what i'm doing without resorting to a toolkit to do half my work. Too many developers do this and the end result is ALWAYS sloppy bloated code that no one understands fully.

Comment: @Stese: Actually, and with all due respect again, I'm a professional programmer for longer than I like to admit, and reinvention of the wheel is not a virtue.  Separation of concerns, maintainability, and unit tested components are.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to ensure that the closing  tag was present in the code, and in the correct location to prevent erroneous iteration!